# Shell reading IP addresses from file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have very long file

```
Feb  2 18:43:05 os sshd[14786]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Connection closed by 2001:778:200:4280::37
Feb  2 18:46:08 os sshd[14788]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Connection closed by 158.129.0.37
Feb  2 18:48:05 os sshd[14790]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Connection closed by 2001:778:200:4280::37
Feb  2 18:48:29 os sshd[14791]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Did not receive identification string from 61.240.144.64
Feb  2 19:46:08 os sshd[14853]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Connection closed by 158.129.0.37
Feb  2 19:48:05 os sshd[14855]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Connection closed by 2001:778:200:4280::37
Feb  2 20:21:42 os sshd[14892]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Accepted keyboard-interactive for evakaz from 2001:778:200:4001:e076:812f:23e7:7e62 port 47889 ssh2
Feb  2 21:20:19 os sshd[14960]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Received disconnect from 2001:778:200:4280::38: 11: disconnected by user
Feb  2 21:21:08 os sshd[14963]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Connection closed by 158.129.0.37
Feb  2 22:31:01 os sshd[15100]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Received disconnect 
from 222.161.4.149: 11:
...
...
```

And in each line there are IP adress. IS it possible to read only IP adresses (not entire file) in shell?

Comment: It's certainly possible to read the file and strip out everything that isn't an IP4/6 address, but, no, you can't do it without reading the entire file at least once, even if it's just to find starting/ending offsets for all the bits you want to extract on a second pass...

Answer (score 1):

For IPv4:

```
$ grep -woE '([[:digit:]]+\.){3}[[:digit:]]+' file
158.129.0.37
61.240.144.64
158.129.0.37
158.129.0.37
222.161.4.149
```

For IPv6:

```
$ grep -oE '([[:xdigit:]]+:){7}[[:xdigit:]]+' file
2001:778:200:4001:e076:812f:23e7:7e62
```

For both:

```
$ grep -oE '([[:xdigit:]]+:){7}[[:xdigit:]]+|([[:digit:]]+\.){3}[[:digit:]]+' file
158.129.0.37
61.240.144.64
158.129.0.37
2001:778:200:4001:e076:812f:23e7:7e62
158.129.0.37
222.161.4.149
```

Comment: sorry but  I get this error
grep: illegal option -- o

Comment: @user3334375 Tell me what OS and version of `grep` you are using.  My tests were run on Linux with GNU  grep v2.12.   I also just checked the manpage for [Mac OSX 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html) and its `grep` supports `-o` also.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you don't reinvent the wheel matching IP addresses:

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -nE '
    say $1 if /$RE{net}{IPv4}{-keep}/; 
    say $1 if /$RE{net}{IPv6}{-keep}/
' file
```

That does require you to install Regexp::Common from CPAN.

From your input, that command outputs

```
2001:778:200:4280::37
158.129.0.37
2001:778:200:4280::37
61.240.144.64
158.129.0.37
2001:778:200:4280::37
2001:778:200:4001:e076:812f:23e7:7e62
2001:778:200:4280::38
158.129.0.37
222.161.4.149
```